# Trying to detect which row of gridview is in edit mode, then when a checkboxfield is checked adjust a textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I've been investigating a few different ways to achieve this. The current one trying to use jquery.

```
//Find each edit link
var chks = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_GVJobList').find('a');
//For each edit link bind click with function
$.each(chks, function () { $(this).on('click', function () {
    // trying to get the calling element
    var $self = $(this);
    // trying to get the parent(cell) then parent(row) then find the checkbox
    alert($($self).parent().parent().find('input:checkbox').val());
}) });
```

It's been a problem for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am open to using any method that would achieve this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVJobList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SDSJobsDetails" OnRowCommand="GV_JobList_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parts/Services">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="B_EditJob" runat="server" CommandName="EditJob" Text="update" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>' CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceID" HeaderText="InvoiceID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FK_CustomerID" HeaderText="FK_CustomerID" SortExpression="FK_CustomerID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalCostExGST" HeaderText="TotalCostExGST" SortExpression="TotalCostExGST" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalGST" HeaderText="TotalGST" SortExpression="TotalGST" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalCost" HeaderText="TotalCost" SortExpression="TotalCost" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AmountPaid" HeaderText="AmountPaid" SortExpression="AmountPaid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Booked" HeaderText="Date_Booked" SortExpression="Date_Booked" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Time_Scheduled" HeaderText="Date_Time_Scheduled" SortExpression="Date_Time_Scheduled" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Completed" HeaderText="Date_Completed" SortExpression="Date_Completed" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Paid" HeaderText="Date_Paid" SortExpression="Date_Paid" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="completed" HeaderText="completed" SortExpression="completed" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="PaidInFull" HeaderText="PaidInFull" SortExpression="PaidInFull" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="PartPaid" HeaderText="PartPaid" SortExpression="PartPaid" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invoice">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="B_CreateInvoice" runat="server" CommandName="CreateInvoice" Text="Create Invoice" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>'  CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                    <asp:Button ID="B_ViewInvoice" runat="server" CommandName="ViewInvoice" Text="View Invoice" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>'  CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                    <asp:Button ID="B_SendInvoice" runat="server" CommandName="SendInvoice" Text="eMail Invoice" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>'  CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Very Difficult to answer without HTML mark-up!

Comment: `Peter` have you tried a google search for working examples on this.? there are plenty of them out there.. here is a good place to start [DataGridView.CommitEdit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit(v=vs.110).aspx) || [DataGridView.EditMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I had tried googling everything I could think of. My last resort was asking here.

Comment: How do I attach the CommitEdit method to the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, DJ KRAZE's suggestion didn't have enough information for me to make it work. But I found a key word combination that Google tossed up part of the answer.

```
protected void chkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) (sender as CheckBox).Parent.Parent;
    CheckBox chk = (sender as CheckBox);
    TextBox comp = row.Cells[11].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    TextBox totalAmt = row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    TextBox paid = row.Cells[8].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    TextBox datePaid = row.Cells[12].Controls[0] as TextBox;

    if (chk.ID.Equals("CB_Completed") && chk.Checked)
    {
        comp.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
    else if (chk.ID.Equals("CB_Completed") && !chk.Checked)
    {
        comp.Text = "";
    }

    if (chk.ID.Equals("CB_PaidInFull") && chk.Checked)
    {
       datePaid.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
       paid.Text = totalAmt.Text;
    }
    else if (chk.ID.Equals("CB_PaidInFull") && !chk.Checked)
    {
        datePaid.Text = "";
        paid.Text = "";
    }
}
```

And the mark-up

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GVJobList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SDSJobsDetails" OnRowCommand="GV_JobList_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parts/Services">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="B_EditJob" runat="server" CommandName="EditJob" Text="update" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>' CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceID" HeaderText="InvoiceID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FK_CustomerID" HeaderText="FK_CustomerID" SortExpression="FK_CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalCostExGST" HeaderText="TotalCostExGST" SortExpression="TotalCostExGST" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalGST" HeaderText="TotalGST" SortExpression="TotalGST" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalCost" HeaderText="TotalCost" SortExpression="TotalCost" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmountPaid" HeaderText="AmountPaid" SortExpression="AmountPaid" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Booked" HeaderText="Date_Booked" SortExpression="Date_Booked" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Time_Scheduled" HeaderText="Date_Time_Scheduled" SortExpression="Date_Time_Scheduled" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Completed" HeaderText="Date_Completed" SortExpression="Date_Completed" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Paid" HeaderText="Date_Paid" SortExpression="Date_Paid" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_Completed" Checked='<%# Bind("completed") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_Completed" Checked='<%# Bind("completed") %>' CommandName="comp" runat="server" Enabled="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PaidInFull">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_PaidInFull" Checked='<%# Bind("PaidInFull") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_PaidInFull" Checked='<%# Bind("PaidInFull") %>' CommandName="full" runat="server" Enabled="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PartPaid">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_PartPaid" Checked='<%# Bind("PartPaid") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_PartPaid" Checked='<%# Bind("PartPaid") %>' CommandName="part" runat="server" Enabled="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invoice">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="B_CreateInvoice" runat="server" CommandName="CreateInvoice" Text="Create Invoice" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>' CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        <asp:Button ID="B_ViewInvoice" runat="server" CommandName="ViewInvoice" Text="View Invoice" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>' CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        <asp:Button ID="B_SendInvoice" runat="server" CommandName="SendInvoice" Text="eMail Invoice" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("InvoiceID") %>' CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

That means there are a few calls to the server and sometimes it can be slow but it does the job. Maybe I'll revisit the whole thing one day and try to get javascript or jquery to work on it.

Basically I replaced the checkboxfield with template fields and checkboxes. This allows me to keep the look the same when not in edit mode and asp.net does the work for me of enabling. This allows me to compare ID's. Then I use AutoPostBack with CheckedChange to detect the change to the checkbox between posts, this is the only way the server can do it (which makes sense).